# How to send email after one hour of the joining in getresponse.com

Tags: php, getresponse

HI all,

I have an account in getresponse.com

I want to send emails to the members in my mailing list after one hour of their joining.

Please tell me how can i do this

Answer (score 3):

I don't really know what's that getresponse.com all about and what are your possibilities, but deducing from php tag:

Php scripts can't execute for an hour => you have to schedule this. You need some database(or at least a file or sth else) to store the information when someone joined and a cron script that's scheduled to run eg. every 5 minutes that checks your database and if the time is right sends an e-mail and then removes the entry from database.

Answer (score 0):

Admin interface allows you to create a follow-up message received by subscriber no sooner than 1 day after their subscription, so you will most likely have to send it through their API call:

http://dev.getresponse.com/api-doc/#send_newsletter